# Only update a cell if it is empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a sheet where column A is "current ETA" and is updated periodically. I want column B to be "initial ETA" so that B takes the first value entered in A, then never changes.

Using standard `IF` statements I obviously run into circular reference issues because I can't do `B1=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,"")`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Properties Service to store the initial ETA globally and then compare against it afterwards.
Write your function using the google scripts and use that function in your `B1` cell.

```
=storeETA(A1)
```

Using `Tools -> Script Editor` you can write the function:

```
function storeETA(a) {
  if(a != 0) {
    if(!PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('initialETA')) {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('initialETA', a);
    }
  }
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('initialETA');
}
```

This way you'll always have that initial data stored.